# xcodebuild target name with Umlaut

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins, xcodebuild

I am trying to build an iOS App using Jenkins via the xcodebuild command.

The problem is that xcodebuild does not detect the target with the German Umlaut ü.

```
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -target AppNameWithUmlautü -configuration Debug clean build
```

gives me following error:

```
xcodebuild: error: The project 'AppNameWithUmlautü.xcodeproj' does not contain a target named 'AppNameWithUmlautü'.
```

I checked the existence of the target using following command:

```
xcodebuild -list

Information about project "AppNameWithUmlautü":
    Targets:
        AppNameWithUmlautü
        AppNameWithOutUmlaut

    Build Configurations:
        Debug
        Release
        Ad Hoc

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used. This project contains no schemes.
```

The target without Umlaut works.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for your answer. It helped to understand the problem, but I ended up renaming the target (using "ue" instead of "ü").

Comment: Yes, that is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode uses the "decomposite" UTF-8 representation for Umlauts in the target name: "ü" is represented as `75 CC 88`. `75` is "u", and `CC 88` is the UTF-8 sequence for the "COMBINING DIAERESIS".

The shell, on the other hand, uses the "composite" UTF-8 representation `C3 BC` for "ü".

So the target that you give on the command line does not match the target name in the Xcode project (and one could argue that this is a bug in Xcode).

I have no knowledge about Jenkins, but if you somehow can use the output of the `xcodebuild -list` command to get the decomposite UTF-8 target name and copy that into your Makefile, shell script or whatever you have, then this should help.